# Signing in a User (Ruby on Rails Tutorial Ch. 8)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Why is the middle method necessary?  It seems to me like it's just an intermediary step to connect the first and third methods.

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the setter method or the helper method to set the `current_user` with the user who is **currently online**. This is used by `devise gem` to identify the current user.

So whenever you need to find the online user for your application, you just use the following code-

```
if current_user
#Do something important   
else
#You do not have enough privileges. Please login.
#Your offline stuff
end
```

Comment: One more question...When the code is run, how does the app progress through the methods?  I think it might help to understand the progression.

Comment: nothing fancy. If you are logging in, `sign_in(user)` method is used. Then after user signed in, the `current_user=(user)` method is used through out. However, if no user is found which is only when user used remember me checkbox then the lookup is from the `remember_token` and `current_user` method is called in this case.